# python dictionary: value and the key not corresponding in my code to find max

Tags: python, sorting, max

My goal is to figure out who has the most message the file is here.[mbox-short.txt](http://www.py4inf.com/code/mbox-short.txt).
My code is here.

```
fhand = open('mbox-short.txt')
counts = dict()

#this loop is to creat a dictionary in which key is the mail's name
#value is times the mail's name appeared
for line in fhand:
    if not (line.startswith('From')and not line.startswith('From:')):
        continue
    words = line.split()
    counts[words[1]] = counts.get(words[1],0) + 1
num = None

#this loop is to find max value and its key
for key, value in counts.items():
    #print key, value
    if num == None or counts[key] > num:
        num = counts[key]
print key, num.
```

After I ran the code. The result is:

But when I run the line *print key,value* in the second loop, comment the line which under the *print key, value*, the result is show that the ray@media.berkeley.edu is 1 instead of 5. The cwen@input.edu is 5.
So why the key and value is not corresponding. I thin the problem is on line 19. How can solve it?

It seemly that I didn't save the key.
Thank you for all.

Thank all of you. I solved it.
In the second loop, I created a variable to save the key

Comment: Please re-indent your code.

Comment: What is the content of your file?

Comment: this code doesn't work without commented line, and `num = None` so you can't get `1` or `5`

Comment: You iterate on the items in `counts` with `for key, value in counts: ...`, but then you ignore `value` inside the loop. Use `value`; there's no need to look up `counts[key]` again. And strictly, you don't need to store the maximum `counts[key]` value so far, only the key that gives it.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if i understand what you want to do. The fist loop should count all address and the second should find the maximum?

You have to inialize `num` with some value, but I would choose zero. Then you haven’t check for `num == None`. And you muss save the key, not only the value. The key will always be the last key in the dict.

Comment: I realize I messed up my code. I will fixed it. My goal is that what you said.

Comment: I have edited my question again. Hope you look at it again. Thank you. Now I know I did not save my key. So how can I save it?

Answer (score 0):

As you realized you need to store the key which gives the max value, or at least max-value-so-far. Then you don't need to store num, the maximum `counts[key]` value so far, only the key that gives it `max_key`.

Also, you iterate on the items in `counts` with `for key, value in counts: ...`, but then you ignore `value` inside the loop. Use `value`; there's no need to look up `counts[key]` again.  And as long as `counts` has >=1 item, you don't need the pessimism of setting `num = None` and then testing against that inside your loop. Anyway, num is unnecessary.

```
# Iterative approach
max_key = counts.keys()[0] # default assumption
for key, value in counts.items():
    if value > counts[max_key]:
        max_key = key
```

but you can avoid all this by directly finding the max without needing to iterate:

```
# Direct approach, using `max(..., key=...)`
max_key = max(counts, key=lambda kv: kv[1])
print max_key, counts[max_key]
cwen@iupui.edu 5
```

This works because Python `sorted(), max(), min()` will accept a dictionary, and they have an optional parameter `key` which allows you to pass in a function telling the comparison which element in each item to use.

Look at the doc for `sorted(), max(), min()`, and read about Python idioms using them.

There is also the custom `collections.Counter` which @Burhan references. But it's important to learn how to sort things first. Then you can use it.

Comment: Thank you! You explain it well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Counter` class, its designed for this exact purpose:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

with open('mbox-short.txt') as f:
   emails = Counter([i.strip() for i in re.findall(r'From:(.*?)', f.read(), re.M)])

for email, count in emails.most_common():
   print('{} - {}'.format(email, count))
```